# What is this operator after ServletContext in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am a complete newbie to Groovy/Grails as well as Java.

I've been following some code example in the Bootstrap class of Grails and stumbled upon a piece of code such as follows.

```
class BootStrap { 
 def init = { servletContext -> 

 } 

 def destroy = {} 
}
```

I do understand what the servletContext is from reading elsewhere, but I could not figure out what the dereference like operator -> after the servletContext was? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `def` like `var` in Javascript and `Object` in Java; so that's setting the variable `init` to `{ servletContext -> }` (putting it on one line for clarity).

That's a Closure, and you can tell them from other expressions because they're blocks of code inside a `{ }` block, with one of 3 forms of arg signature. If there are no args defined (like in the `destroy` closure below) then there is actually one arg named `it`.  That's like `i` in the traditional for loop - you could use an elaborate name, but if it doesn't matter, `it` is as good as any. It's auto-generated by the compiler, and if you want to name it you can and no `it` will exist.

If there are one or more explicitly named args, then there's no automatic `it`, and you need a delimiter between the args block  and the start of the code - that's what `->` does and it's required whether everything is on one line (where is needed) or on multiple lines, where theoretically at a smaller local store

Finally, if there really are zero args, e.g. like the closure equivalent of a simple getter `int getFoo() { ... }` then  you name it as you like and add the `->` operator to make it clear that there are no args (not even `it`): `def fooGetter = { -> ... }`

Comment: I realize now that I needed to understand closures in Groovy in order to grasp this concept. Appreciate your response. Does closures accept more than one arguments? E.g. 'def foo = { arg1, arg2 -> ...}'

Comment: Yep, they certainly do. There are a bunch of really useful groovy tutorials on the codehaus website. [This one](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) is probably a useful one for you to have a read through.